# Countable and Uncountable set prove or give counterexample

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove or give counter examples for the false ones.Suppose that $E$ is a set. If there exists a function $f$ from $E$ onto $\mathbb{N}$ then $E$ is at most countable.

Suppose that $E$ is the empty set. Then by definition $E$ is at most countable. Beyond that I am having hard time showing different scenarios. Part of the issue I think is that the function is from $E$ onto $\mathbb{N}$ However in this section everything is about the $\mathbb{N}$ onto $E$.

Comment: Can you think of a surjection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb N$?

Comment: Consider $E = \{ \mathbb{N} \}$.

Comment: If $E = \mathbb{N}$ then $E$ is 1-1 and onto correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counterexample: Let $E=\mathbb R.$ Define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb N$ by setting $f(n)=n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $f=1$ elsewhere.